# Laravel 5.2 authentication multipe fields

Tags: laravel, authentication

My app is using the standard Auth module to login using email and a password combo.

I need to modify it so a user can either enter an email or a unique 7-digit code with a password.

On the Laravel docs I found this bit of code.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

I've already modifed the table to include the proper code, but haven't figured out how to do the authentication.

Has anyone else ran into this type of problem before? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use regular expression to detect if input is an email or a code, then attempt based on what you have

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `AuthController` override (add) the `getCredentials` method as follows:

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $login = filter_var($request->input('login'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'digits'; //Change digits to your table column name
    return [
        $login => $request->input('login'),
        'password' => $request->input('password') //you can add any db field here e.g: "active" => 1
    ];
}
```

For validation you need to override `validateLogin` too:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'login' => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

**Don't forget** to change the input **name** to `login` in your view !

Answer (score 0):

I believe Laravel Authentication the 'email' field is just a string and there is no imposed validation on the field as an email (except for the view template field implementation). So, you can easily replace the field with another 'username' field of your choice and perform your own validation on it during creation.

Note this excerpt from the authentication page https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication

```
Note: In these examples, email is not a required option, it is merely used as an example. You should use whatever column name corresponds to a "username" in your database.
```